# SSIS write DT_NTEXT into an UTF-8 csv file

Tags: csv, utf-8, ssis

I need to write the result of an SQL query into a CSV file (UTF-8 (I need this encoding as there are French letters)). One of the columns is too large (more than 20000 char) so I can't use DT_WSTR for it. The type that is inputted is DT_TEXT so I use a Data Conversion to change it to DT_NTEXT. But then when I want to write it to the file I have this error message :

> Error 2   Validation error. The data type for "input column" is
>   DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead
>   and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component

Is there a way I can write the data to my file?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing just like Samyne says, I used a script.
First I've modified my SQL SP, instead of having several columns I put all the info in one single column like follows :

```
Select Column1 + '^' + Column2 + '^' + Column3 ...
```

Then I used this code in a script

```
            string fileName = Dts.Variables["SLTemplateFilePath"].Value.ToString();

            using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate))
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {

                    OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["FileData"].Value);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(row[column]);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
            }
```

Putting all the info in one column is optional, I just wanted to avoid handling it in the script, this way if my SP is changed I don't need to modify the SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of issues also sometimes. When working with data larger than 255 characters SSIS sees it as blob data and will always handle this as such.

I then converted this blob stream data to a readable text with a script component. Then other transformation should be possible.

This was the case in ssis that came with sql server 2008 but I believe this isn't changed yet.